# PDF Icon changes to blank in Dropbox folder

Tags: windows-8, dropbox, file-association

Strange enough, the PDF reader icon corrupts in my Dropbox folder on my Windows 8 machine. I am using Windows 8 x64 Pro.

If I change the "open with" to some other reader and then back to Adobe Acrobat Reader, it shows the PDF icon and preview of the PDF file. But somehow it MAGICALLY corrupts sometime later and the PDF file gets a blank icon. Possibly corruption of thumbs.db in Dropbox during synchronization?

This screenshot is in the root folder of my Dropbox folder on my Windows 8 machine.

[image: blank icons]

Comment: Please try to take a little bit more care to use proper grammar, spelling, and capitalization when writing posts. Anyhow, does this only occur in your dropbox folder, and not anywhere else?

Comment: I am not sure why this thing does not replicates with other people. Do you have any clue if fixing thumbs.db for this would be helpful ?

Comment: @Windows8Fanatic: You can safely remove (or rename to be even more safe, so you could rename it back) these files. Have you also tried to reinstall Adobe Reader or resync with Dropbox in another folder to see if it also happens there? There might be a hidden `desktop.ini` file which causes this to happen...

Comment: @TomWijsman i can try re-installing Adobe Acrobat Reader, renaming file doesn't changes anything. Anyways that's not the solution i seek as well. Re synching Dropbox with 16 Gigs, its a tough call i can try it though. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

They just released V1.4.20 which is the first version with Windows 8 specific fixes (notification area icon for example).

If this version does not fix it I suggest you wait a bit as it seems the dropbox team is a little late to win 8.

I've seen numerous other bugs floating around the web when installing the OS so I think it is just a matter of time.

Tell me if this version works for you!

Comment: Upgrading the version still does not resolves the issue. Problem persists at my end.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that :(. If you can test on another win 8 machine + dropbox you could see if the problem is only on your pc or widespread. If it is widespread only an update will solve it. Maybe try to install Win8 in a virtual machine to test.

Comment: thank you once again. My Windows install has been recent (Aug 2012). I had this issue with my last installation of Windows and that time i was under impression it is due to RC version of Windows, but it occurred in RTM as well. I hope a new update is the only thing that might resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the default viewer for the PDF to Reader and then back to Adobe PDF. It fixed a similar issue I had. Also rebooted due to Windows Updates. Was either the update or the default program switch that kicked it in.

Comment: Changed the default reader initially and the issue was not repeating with Windows default PDF reader ..But i dont want to stick with Windows reader but with Acrobat PDF reader.